# How can I sort source files in task?

Tags: sorting, gradle

I have a combineJs task from gradle-js-plugin:

```
combineJs {

    def jsFiles = fileTree(dir: "/lib/", include: "jquery.js")
    jsFiles += fileTree(dir: "/lib/plugins", include: "*.js") //.sort()
    jsFiles += fileTree(dir: "/lib/", include: "underscore.js")

    source = jsFiles
    dest = file("/js/all.js")
}
```

I want to sort plugins in natural order, because when it combines on unix it is in different order than on windows.

How can I do it? I Have tried many different ways.

For instance:

```
combineJs {

    def jsFiles = fileTree(dir: "/lib/", include: "jquery.js")
    jsFiles += fileTree(dir: "/lib/plugins", include: "*.js") //.sort()
    jsFiles += fileTree(dir: "/lib/", include: "underscore.js")

    source = jsFiles.collect { File file -> relativePath(file) }.sort().each { fileTree(it) }
    dest = file("/js/all.js")
}
```

Comment: It might be worth briefly explaining what ways/methods you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
List<File> ll = new ArrayList<>(jsFiles.getFiles())
Collections.sort(ll)
```

Comment: Or `source = jsFiles.files.sort()`.